# Here-string not working if you indent in vscode

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Having this works as expected:

```
$toAdd = @"
{
"name": $SomeVar,
"value" : "app"
}
"@
```

But if I indent it - tyo keep some structure in a function lets say:
Note "linex" is just to illustrate the indention

```
 line1:     $toAdd = @"
 line2:     {
 line3:     "name": $SomeVar,
 line4:     "value" : "app"
 line5:     }
 line6:     "@
```

Then I get: `White space is not allowed before the string terminator.PowerShell`

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Unfortunately the `"@` close token for here-strings must appear in column 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd love to be proven wrong (please!) but no, heredoc strings need to be formatted without indent in Powershell to be understood.

```
$heredocHaiku = @"
I have to be left
flush against the console's start
to be recognized
"@
```

Comment: To clarify: Lines indented inside the here-string will be indented as many spaces as you use (all strings contained within do not have to start at column 1). The only requirement is that the close token for the here-string (`"@`) must be start in column 1.

Answer (score 1):

You could just declare the `Here-String` at the top of your script, and apply the appropriate [Scope Modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-5.1#scope-modifiers) to the variable.  Then you don't have to worry about indentation, snf having it look ugly, such as if the here-string was nested inside a `function`:

```
# Top of script
$script:code = @"
Hear ye, hear ye
Here's a here-string
"@
```